# Kotlin handle a different type in constructor

Tags: class, kotlin, constructor, data-class

lets say that for an example I have a data class that's like this

data class AB(a: String, b: String)

how do I make a constructor (or if there is any other way) handle a different type, for example if get an "a" variable as an Int and I want to handle it and covert it to a string?

Thanks!

Comment: What are all the types that you want to handle?

Comment: @zuninjo: Add a constructor: _constructor(a: Int, b: String) : this(a.toString(), b)_

Comment: You can add a [secondary constructor](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/classes.html#secondary-constructors). Or you could declare a top-level function that converts the other types into a `String` and then calls `AB`'s primary constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious answer is using a secondary constructor, but this might be too restrictive in what it does. In this case, probably only really a good idea if you want a simple `.toString()` call. (see `a`)

You could also put the conversion logic in some function defined outside your class or in the companion object (see `b`). But I feel like you'd usually end up with more readable code by just using a factory method on the companion object at that point (see `c`).

```
data class AB(val a: String){
    constructor(a: Double): this(a.toString())
    constructor(b: Int): this(fromInt(b))
    companion object {
        fun fromInt(b: Int) = "this is my string: $b"
        fun create(c: Int) = AB("this is my string: $c")
    }
}

val ab: AB = AB.create(2)
```

Comment: Im getting confused if I have more variables in data class, if AB(a: String, b: String) for example, how do I only convert "b" variable if its passed as a string?

Comment: @zuninjo Kotlin is statically typed. You can't pass any arbitrary type to the constructor. If all you have is `data class AB(val a: String, val b: String)` then only instances of `String` can be passed to the primary constructor as arguments for `a` and `b`.  So, if you want to accept other types that are then converted to `String`, then you need to explicitly add the necessary secondary constructors (or add top-level/companion "factory" functions) for each desired type.  And if you want to mix and match types, then you'll need to add such constructors/functions _for every combination_.

Comment: @zuninjo As you can probably imagine, that will get unmanageable really quick. You should only do this for a small number of _extremely common_ use cases, if even that. Typically, you should let the consumer of your API handle passing the correct type, doing any conversions as needed on their end.